# Поведение метода __exit__

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, менеджер-контекста

Что должен возвращать метод `__exit__`? В [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__exit__) сказано, что если я возвращаю `true`, то исключение будет обработано. Если я ничего не возвращаю, то исключение пропускается. А что если я возвращаю `false` или что-то ещё? Как тогда? Как это реализовано? Поясните.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Перевод абзаца про возвращаемое значение:

> Если предоставлено исключение, и метод хочет подавить исключение (т. е. предотвратить его распространение), он должен вернуть истинное значение. В противном случае исключение будет обработано нормально при выходе из этого метода.

Т.е. `__exit__` должен вернуть `True`, если в блоке `with` исключения были обработаны самой функцией `__exit__`. Если же в блоке `with` возникло исключение, которое вы не обрабатываете в функции `__exit__`, или же не было исключений вовсе, то эта самая функция должна возвращать `False`.

Обращаю внимание на то, что в `__exit__` нужно обрабатывать исключение не через блок `try-except`, а исходя из предоставленного исключения.

Если в блоке `with` возникает исключение, вызывается функция `__exit__`, и в качестве параметров передаются `exc_type`, `exc_value`, `traceback`, т.е. внутри функции вы точно знаете тип вызванного исключения, значение (комментарий) исключения, и у вас есть трейсбек.

Если в блоке `with` исключений не возникает, функция `__exit__` вызывается с `None`-параметрами в конце блока `with`.